# realm leave did not remove AD DNS records

Tags: dns

when I issue command "realm leave  --user=administrator --verbose" to disjoin ubuntu from AD, it successfully remove my computer object from AD.  However, it didn't remove DNS record from AD DNS.

Is there anything that I can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

**nsupdate** utility can be used, which can manage dymamic DNS records.

To install on Debian/Ubuntu systems:

```
apt-get install dnsutils
```

on Centos/Redhat systems:

```
yum install bind-utils
```

For example, let's use server with name **testserver** in domain **testdomain** with ip address **10.10.0.5**.

First of all, we need to find it's DNS records :

```
dig +noall +answer testserver.testdomain 
dig +noall +answer -x 10.10.0.5
```

The result will be something like that:

```
testserver.testdomain.  3600 IN A   10.10.0.5
5.0.10.10.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN PTR testserver.testdomain.
```

To authenticate on DNS server, Kerberos credentials are required, so you need to obtain key for the server acccount:

```
kinit -k TESTSERVER$
```

Execute **nsupdate** with *-g* option, to use standard GSS-TSIG mode for authentication and *-v* option, to use a TCP connection:

```
nsupdate -g -v
```

Specify name server:

```
> server <dns_server_hostname>
```

Command to remove PTR record:

```
> update delete 5.0.10.10.in-addr.arpa. PTR
```

After that, blank line needs to be introduced between removal of the PTR record and the A record:

```
>
```

Command to remove A record:

```
> update delete testserver.testdomain. A
```

Sent update request to name server:

```
> send
```

This must be executed before server leaving domain, of course.